# How to add a text in the captured image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, streamlit

I have created a app which capture the image and convert into pencil sketch.

I need to add a watermark inside the capture image I find for the documentation I didn't get the exact one let me know how to add a water mark inside the image or any idea would be appreciated.

```
import base64
import streamlit as st 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image  
import cv2 

def dodgeV2(x, y):
    return cv2.divide(x, 255 - y, scale=256)

def pencilsketch(inp_img):
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(inp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_invert = cv2.bitwise_not(img_gray)
img_smoothing = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_invert, (21, 21),sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)
final_img = dodgeV2(img_gray, img_smoothing)
logo_img = cv2.imread("Watertext.jpg")
logo_gray = cv2.cvtColor(logo_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
logo_height, logo_width = logo_gray.shape[:2]
#y_offset = x_offset = 0 # paste to the top left of image
x_offset = final_img.shape[1] - logo_width
y_offset = 0
final_img[x_offset:x_offset+logo_height, y_offset:y_offset+logo_width] = logo_gray
return(final_img)
```

[image: Water Mark]

Comment: this question doesn't actually use streamlit... why did you tag it so? why did you not tag the other libraries, that you actually use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `pencilsketch` function like

```
def pencilsketch(inp_img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(inp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_invert = cv2.bitwise_not(img_gray)
    img_smoothing = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_invert, (21, 21),sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)
    final_img = dodgeV2(img_gray, img_smoothing)
    logo_img = cv2.imread("path/to/logo/image.jpg")
    logo_gray = cv2.cvtColor(logo_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    logo_height, logo_width = logo_gray.shape[:2]
    x_offset = y_offset = 0 # paste to the top left of image
    final_img[y_offset:y_offset+logo_height, x_offset:x_offset+logo_width] = logo_gray
    return(final_img)
```

---

If you want to paste in top right, change line

```
    x_offset = y_offset = 0 # paste to the top left of image
```

to

```
    x_offset = final_img.shape[1] - logo_width
    y_offset = 0
```

---

If you want to paste in bottom right, change line

```
    x_offset = y_offset = 0 # paste to the top left of image
```

to

```
    x_offset = final_img.shape[1] - logo_width
    y_offset = final_img.shape[0] - logo_height
```

Comment: I am facing this issue after adding your code could not broadcast input array from shape (27,107,3) into shape (27,107)

Comment: @Fariya I've updated my answer, because you converted captured image to gray scale, so logo image must be gray scale

Comment: Thanks a lot... What to do if i want to change the position like top right or bottom right

Comment: You need to change offset, I've updated my answer, look at it

Comment: You got that error in which line?

Comment: I've update my typo variable in my answer

Comment: I have updated the pencil sketch function in above code kindly check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247113/discussion-between-fariya-and-anhpc03).

Comment: You have to use `final_img[y_offset:y_offset+logo_height, x_offset:x_offset+logo_width] = logo_gray. Please note that `y` is before, and `x` is after, not as you edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247122/discussion-between-fariya-and-anhpc03).

Answer (score -1):

using OpenCV you can add a watermark on your photos and video also, you need to import the library and use it.

```
**import cv2
img = cv2.imread('diego-jimenez-A-NVHPka9Rk-unsplash.JPG')
watermark = cv2.imread("Watermark.JPG")**
```

for more references go to [this blog post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/how-to-add-watermark-on-images-using-opencv-in-python/)

Comment: Facing issues while adding this code @Devang it would be great if you make changes in my code

Comment: I already mention this link-  https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/how-to-add-watermark-on-images-using-opencv-in-python/ please go through it.

Answer (score -1):

Make use of `cv2.addWeighted()` which is used to blend images.
This is an example:

```
output_img = cv2.addWeighted(input_img, 1, watermark, 0.5, 0)
```

Comment: i have tried but i am getting this  error cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'addWeighted'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src1 is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src1'

Comment: input_img and watermark image should have same width and height. So, use cv2.resize() to change the image resolution and then pass the images to cv2.addWeighted().